# Bayesian networks tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks

For a beginner, which is the best book to start with for studying Bayesian Networks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend "Probabilistic Graphical Models" by Daphne Koller and Nir Friedman. Its an excellent starter-to-intermediate handbook on both directed (Bayesian Networks) and undirected (Markov Networks) graphical models. The examples given are elaborate and easy to understand.

Comment: Koller is/was teaching a class on probabilistic graphical model on Coursera: https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm

Answer (score 9):

A good book on general machine learning is [1](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html). But it is quite light on BN. I haven't read  [2] but I have read [3] by him which is good (so, [2] is likely to be good as recommended by dwf). I would not recommend Pearl's book at all unless you are doing your Ph.D.!

However, I actually would recommend the online tutorial "**A Brief Introduction to Graphical Models and Bayesian Networks**" by Kevin Murphy [4]. The best way to learn BN is to read this, download his Matlab toolbox [5] and build your own BN in ten minutes.

1. Pattern classification by Duda/Hart/Stork
2. Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Chris Bishop
3. Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition by Chris Bishop
4. http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html
5. Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab

Answer (score 8):

You should check for AI (Artificial Intelligence) books. I've learn about Bayesian  in [Artificial Intelligence "A modern approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)".

Comment: So did I. It was an interesting read.

Answer (score 4):

This online book has been extremely helpful for me in all aspects of machine learning, including Bayesian inference:

http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html

Granted you are familiar with basic probability theory, its a great resource.

Answer (score 4):

All the books mentioned so far are pretty good ones. Pearl's is generally regarded as being a bit hard to follow, it's also quite expensive, but if you can manage it, all the power to you.

I'd really *really* recommend you check out Chris Bishop's book, [*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/). I think it's far and away the best treatment you're going to get of graphical models in a textbook, at least until [Michael Jordan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/) finishes and publishes his book on the subject.

Comment: plus one, especially Bishop's Book (but requires that you read math well)

Answer (score 4):

The best professors in this fields are by my point of view these 2 guys:[link text](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1) Ng. Andrew and [link text](http://www.eetindia.co.in/VIDEO_DETAILS_700000078.HTM) Prof. Pallab Dasgupta.

I have been watching all their tutorials on BBN and they were very usefull.Just follow the links and you will find more AI lectures with this 2 interesting guys.

Have fun learning with them,
Mike

Comment: both led to 404

Answer (score 3):

Pearl's 1988 *Probabilistic Reasoning in Intelligent Systems* is the one of the most cited works on Bayesian Networks.  I found it quite clear. That said, a lot has been done in the field since 1988. It would be wise to supplement this book with more recent works.

Answer (score 1):

Mitchell's *Machine Learning* is an extremely important primer in the area of AI.  It covers Bayesian Networks, devoting, as I recall, an entire chapter to it.

I'd also check out Weka's Bayesian Network class to understand a practical implementation.  If you don't know about Weka, check it out here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/